# How to save a Colab notebook as a template for future notebooks

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to save a Colab Notebook as a template for reuse with future projects.
I often write notebooks that import Kaggle data and these notebooks all have the same first few lines of code.  create like a "Kaggle notebook" template that I can easily reuse for future projects?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes you can.**
First, you will have to create the notebook you want to use as a template. Be sure to add a text field to identify the snippet.
([Add a header to identify the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKfZX.png))

Click on the settings icon on the top right corner of your notebook and paste the link to the notebook(Just copy from the address bar) in the form field.
([Custom snippet notebook URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGMbh.png))
Click on save.

Open any notebook of your choice and navigate to code snippets on the sidebar. Search for the code snippet you just created(use the header name you provided in the text field) and double click to add it to your notebook.
([load snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MtYo.png))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define it as a function then save it as (.Py) and then Import the module from your drive.